# Insert a column with the table id in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tables that show seller_id but not the seller name, which I only specified in the table id,

How can I query this table to include a column with the table_id, so I can get both seller_id and table_id?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
select _TABLE_SUFFIX as table_id, *
from `YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.YOUR_DATASET_NAME.*`
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
--limit 10
```

This will bring table name on each row as first column.

OR

If you already have mapping somewhere, where you keep seller_id to seller_name Then just use that mapping as join and get seller_name as another column in select. I believe this will be a better idea than first workaround.

OR

If its just one seller, just hardcode the seller name as static column into select. (least recommended)